# How to test Material-UI Popover close implementation

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, integration-testing, react-testing-library

I would like to make sure that my implementation of a [Popover](https://mui.com/components/popover/) element combined with a trigger button works as expected.
I was unable to have a working test for asserting that the Popover gets closed after the user presses esc. I was able to make this test work with Modal, but I must use a Popover in my current project.

Component code:

```
import {
    Button, Popover,
} from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';

export default function SimpleModal() {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);

    const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'user-menu' : undefined;

    return (
        <>
            <Button
                aria-controls={id}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                Open Modal
            </Button>

            <Popover open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
                    <h1>Text in Modal</h1>
            </Popover>
        </>
    );
}
```

Test file code:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import SimpleModal from './SimpleModal';

test('should close when esc key is pressed', async () => {
    render(<SimpleModal />);
    userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Open Modal'));
    expect(screen.getByText('Text in Modal')).toBeInTheDocument();
    userEvent.keyboard('{esc}');
    await expect(screen.queryByText('Text in Modal')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: You forgot to wrap the last `expect` in a `waitFor`, e.g. `await waitFor(() => expect(...));`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As suggested by @juliomalves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889380/how-to-test-material-ui-popover-close-implementation/69997694#comment123679524_69889380), wrapping the last `expect` in a `waitFor` corrected the test:

```
await waitFor(() => expect(...));
```